# Splitting Text Content By Newline Not Working

Tags: javascript, split, newline

all. I've been doing some digging around and still can't seem to resolve this issue.

I'm trying to break up some text by every line that occurs. However, no form of regEx newline or carriage returns seems to work with split().

**EDIT:** Is it that I haven't manually inserted any newlines/line breaks? Is it that no newlines have been generated by the time the function runs? (Which wouldn't make sense because it's in the body.

Here's my practice code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to perfom a global search for the letters "ain" in a string, and display the matches.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo" style="width:490px; background:#ddd;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur at commodo enim. Integer dolor elit, elementum vitae mollis eu, lobortis fringilla diam. Maecenas consectetur malesuada sodales. Fusce nec est est, ut bibendum orci. Aenean tellus lectus, consectetur <br> a mattis a, lobortis sit amet mauris. In vitae orci odio. Integer id massa ac elit suscipit bibendum. Vivamus a magna vitae felis ullamcorper elementum. Mauris aliquam euismod elit a mattis. Nam eu felis sed dolor sodales egestas. Sed quis quam augue. Proin bibendum iaculis felis vel pretium. Praesent ultrices sapien eget ante convallis ac iaculis lectus porta. Quisque vel lectus vel nibh facilisis auctor. Donec ac erat est, non pulvinar urna.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.split(/[\r\n]+/); //PROBLEM HERE???
    var line = res[0];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br><br>' + line;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a number of regex expressions and nothing seems to work.

```
/\r/
/\n/
/\r\n/
/\r?\n/
/\r?\n/g
/[\r\n]+/
```

And probably more. The returned value is always "undefined".

Please help!

Comment: Add some line break in your text, then your regex will work.

Comment: @HassanImam or he could use `str.split(/<br>/)` (there's one actual `<br>` in that sample text as of now)

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` represents the HTML as it is written in your document (or maybe slightly normalized). The DOM represents the semantic content of the page; layout occurs on the DOM, but visual effects such as line wrapping are only displayed, not reflected back into the DOM. If you are determined, there is likely a way to determine how the lines are wrapped, but it is probably not trivial. If that's what you're interested in doing, maybe see this other question: [Can I use the browser's word-wrapping from JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3050378)

Comment: I actually just thought about just that and changed it to textContent, but that bit about the line wrapping seems to be the bigger issue I was suspecting. But, thank you. I'll give that thread a look.